# Call a variable in tkinter button, which also runs a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, global-variables, registry

New to Python and starting out, so be gentle. This was edited based on some comments for clean up. I haven't been able to get a working version by shrinking this down to post, but I think it gets the question and problem across easily.

I have 2 fuctions. func1 is set by user activity. Func 2 has two parameters, one of those is the output of func1, the other comes from a dictionary.

How can I get the variable combining the two functions, and the dictionary, to be accessible by any means (print, return, etc) within the tkinter button command section?

```
import tkinter as tk

# Just for this example, storing variables. Actual gathers file paths from user action
num1 = 2
num2 = 3
dict1 = [1, 2, 3]
#Global
sample1 = None

def func1_click():  # This updates sample1 value from user interaction
    global sample1
    sample1 = 1 * 2
    return sample1

def func2 (num1, num2):  # This is called last
    sample2 = num1 * num2
    return sample2

button1 = tk.Button(command=func1_click)
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(command=lambda: print(var2))  
button2.pack()

var2 = func2(sample1, dict1)  # So get this, to ^^^
# Call var2 from button2, run funct2 with output from sample1, and dict1

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question is desperately in need of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  There is a lot of detail here concerning your overall problem, but precious little about your exact problem for this case.  An MCVE would show examples of the data you are receiving, and what you would to hope to be able to process that data into.

Comment: "Create a variable from 2 functions + 1 var" is very, very vague. What problem are you having accomplishing this task? Why two functions? Have you tried creating a new function that calls the other two functions?

Comment: Apologies, I tried to update the original post. am having a hard time shrinking everything down to get the problem across.  In as simplistic form as I can (sorry, new to python), I have output from `function1` that updates a global variable. I then have a `dictionary` storing values. I am trying to call `function2` (which uses 2 parameters, the output from 'function1', and my 'dictionary') from a button on tkinter. it goes to a variable, that I am trying to have run the function and gather the previously stored variables to give me output, as semi-shown as `var2`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the most efficient or cleanest way to do this, but I was able to get this working by creating a list of the combinations comprised of of the various outcomes.

I then created a new function with a global variable which was used in the tkinter button command= section

```
def print_var3():
    global output1
    output =  output1
    print(output1)

button = tk.Button(root, command=print(output1))
button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Now I didn't just want to print, I just needed to confirm Python was returning my results I wanted correctly to use in another function.

Maybe someone can still provide some additional or cleaner methods to this.